# Start the week on Monday in the Clock applet in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, calendar

When clicking on the Clock applet (Clock version 2.26.0) in Gnome (Ubuntu Jaunty) a calendar is shown. Each week starts on Sunday, but I want Monday as starting day. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this depends on your locale.

you need to check LC_TIME
change first_weekday from 1(sunday) to 2(monday)

i just googled and this seems quite a comprehensive guide:

> 1. Make a copy of your locale file in your home directory
>      
>    `cp /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US ~/en_US_modified`
> 2. create a directory "locales" 
>      
>    `mkdir ~/locales`
> 3. open up en_US_modified in an editor, search for the section called
>      "LC_TIME"
> 4. look for the line
>      
>      `first_weekday 1`
> 5. Change the 1 to a 2
> 6. Save the file, exit your editor and go back to the terminal
> 7. Run this command which will create a directory full of new locale
>      settings inside of the "locales" directory you made in your home
>      directory:
>      
>      `localedef -c -i ~/en_US_modified -f UTF-8 ~/locales/en_US.utf8`
> 8. Backup your old locale settings by going to /usr/lib/locale and
>      changing the name of 
>    `en_US.utf8` to `en_US.utf8_ORIGINAL`
> 9. Copy the new en_US.utf8 directory your created in your home
>      directory in the subdir "locales" to `/usr/lib/locale`
> 10. Restart your system

Reference: http://dunedin.lug.net.nz/forums/showthread.php?t=208155 ; reformatted for superuser by me

Comment: Wow... I'll see if I think it's worth it to go through that. If not, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: note that it will change *ALL* programs... unless, of course, you changed the applet run to "e.g. LC_ALL=en_US.cal appletname" and then you need to make clone of a new en_US clone with the necessary changes. ehm, actually i haven't been linux for ages. this brings back my memory when i was doing locale debugging for debian potato (that is yearS ago...)

Comment: OMG. Sorry I lol'd on this one. 2010, desktop use. :D

Comment: @Shiki: I love Linux, I run versions of Ubuntu on all my computers (work and home) and nothing else, but things like this helps me avoid becoming a fanatic :)

Comment: @bubu: There's no problem for me if it changes all programs. Here in Sweden the week starts with Monday.

Comment: @snowlord - Thats not what I meant... but canonical should speed up those papercuts/usability improvements.

Answer (score 5):

Just set LC_TIME to a locale that starts its week on monday. eg: LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8

Make that change permanent by editing `/etc/default/locale` (or `/etc/locale.conf` on some distros)

The best way is to set your locale is on a per user setting, for example in gdm at login. If there is a specific need for more complex things, you can set the locale in /etc. Note that this will affect all users on the system.

Comment: +1 because this is the easy way. shouldn't we really set LANG? anyway, I tried several locales on ubuntu 12.10, including it_IT, and all result in `cal` to show the Sunday as first weekday. probably worth a bug report.

Comment: +1 `LC_TIME` is the thing you should change to get different display of times and dates. `LANG` is the environment variable that defines the *language* of messages to display and should have nothing to do with times or dates.

Comment: The fact that `cal` does not follow locale is by design (see `man cal`). Use `ncal -b` if you want the same thing with correct locale.